SpyGlass lint checks the warning: Signal xxx is being assigned multiple times
My code looks like this
always_comb begin
        awready_tmp     = 1'b0;
        queue_id_tmp    = {QIDW{1'b0}};
        node_id_tmp     = {NIDW{1'b0}};
        if(i_awvalid && addr_fifo_nfull)begin
            for(int i = 0; i < QNUM; i = i + 1)begin
                if(queue_busy[i] == 1'b1 && queue_awid[i] == i_awid)begin
                    if(queue_node_nfull[i] == 1'b1)begin
                        awready_tmp     = 1'b1;
                        queue_id_tmp    = i;  // spyglass disable W310
                        node_id_tmp     = node_wptr[i][NIDW-1:0];
                    end
                    break;
                end else if(i == QNUM-1 && ~(&queue_busy))begin
                    awready_tmp     = 1'b1;
                    queue_id_tmp    = queue_avalible_bin;
                    node_id_tmp     = node_wptr[queue_avalible_bin][NIDW-1:0];
                    
                end
            end
        end
    end


As you can see, the three signals in the always block (awready_tmp, queue_id_tmp, node_id_tmp) actually won't be assigned multiple times because of the break.
However, when I finished the SpyGlass Lint check, Lint reported a warning:
Signal xxx is being assigned multiple times(assignment within same for-loop ) in same always block
Here is the picture of the report:

I want to clear this warning.  How do I need to modify my code?

Contact Synopsys about their SpyGlass lint tool.  They will explain why their tool generates warnings with your code.  They can also offer advice about automatically waiving the warnings.  Look at the SpyGlass documentation to see if it elaborates on the W415a warning; perhaps there is more detailed information regarding this warning type.
It is unusual to see a break statement in synthesizable code.  Perhaps the developers of the SpyGlass software have not taken this syntax into account.
Lastly, if you haven't already done so, you should synthesize your code to make sure you get the results that you expect.  Although the warning may not make sense to you, it may be an indication that the synthesis tool is not going to produce the result you desire.
